# Excel VBA - Add value from input box to list in column

Tags: vba, excel, validation, input

I'm currently making an expense form but I'm struggling for a list of expense categories, I want to make it so that I can type the category I choose in an input box, that then goes in a list which is used as a data validation.
I want the values to add into column A on Sheet2

I've tried the below so far

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim ExpenseName As String

    ExpenseName = InputBox( _
      "Type in the name of the category you want to add", _
      "Add Expense Category", _
      "Type expense category here")

    If Len(ExpenseName) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No category chosen"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    '**Struggling what to put here**
End Sub
```

I have added the below, please see.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim ExpenseName As String
ExpenseName = InputBox( _
"Type in the name of the category you want to add", _
"Add Expense Category", _
"Type expense category here")
If Len(ExpenseName) = 0 Then
MsgBox "No category chosen"
Exit Sub
End If
Dim strList As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim eRow As Long

eRow = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D4:D21").Validation
    .Delete      'Delete previous validation
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
        Formula1:="=Sheet2!$A$1:$A$" & eRow
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided there is already validation in the range, you could do something like this (not tested):

EDITED:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim ExpenseName As String
Dim eRow as Long

ExpenseName = InputBox( _
    "Type in the name of the category you want to add", _
    "Add Expense Category", _
    "Type expense category here")

If Len(ExpenseName) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No category chosen"
    Exit Sub
End If

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    eRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    .Cells(eRow, "A").Value = ExpenseName
End With

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D4:D21").Validation
    .Delete      'Delete previous validation
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
        Formula1:= "=Sheet2!$A$1:$A$" & eRow
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried this and it shows 'Run-time error '1004':

Application-defined or object-defined error @Jordan

Comment: `strList = .Formula1`

Comment: Okay, it could be because the range which the validation applies to is different, I've updated the answer now. What is the range that the data validation applies to?

Comment: Data validation is on cells `D4:D21` and pulls the list of data from `Sheet2 A1:A5` but obviously that list of data is going to expand

Comment: Oh I see, I was doing the formula based on you having a string as the formula as opposed to a range of cells. Do you want the range of cells to simply be updated? - I'll update the answer now because the data validation is on the wrong cells

Comment: I've added the updated code, please see OP, is this now correct?

Comment: Sorry forgot one bit, my answer now contains the full code. It will add the new list item to column A in Sheet2 then the validation will be updated to match this new addition.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! Thankyou.